# Lightbox gallery rel with array parameter validation

Tags: html, w3c-validation

I am trying to validate a page in which I have implemented Lightbox and W3C thinks rel="lightbox['gallery']" is invalid code. Code is :

```
<a rel="lightbox[gallery]" href="link-to-image">

  ...image...

</a>
```

Error:

```
Bad value lightbox[gallery] for attribute rel on element a: Keyword lightbox[gallery] is not registered.
```

Any insight into this is welcomed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At least for me it's more comfortable to use "target" instead of "rel" or "data-rel" (which is not a standard link attribute anyway), thus still pass w3 HTML5 validation and do not mess with page's CSS setup ("class" is commonly used for layout and such). Of course all "*.getAttribute('rel')" in javascript source has to be updated accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to validate HTML5, right?

It's simple enough I'm afraid; whereas HTML4 allows pretty much any content in rel, HTML5 is much stricter and "lightbox[gallery]" isn't a registered rel type.

I've seen a fix which should work: get Lightbox to look for class="lightbox[gallery]" instead of rel="lightbox[gallery]", but so far my inept tweaks haven't worked. I'm trying to contact the Lightbox dev to ask him about this, but his forum is giving 500 errors. Not a good sign. :(

Answer (score 0):

Or a better idea - in my opinion ofc - instead of `rel` use `data-rel`. But also you have to modify lightbox a little bit ;-)

Answer (score 0):

With Lightbox2, you should use

```
<strong><a data-lightbox="lightbox[gallery]" href="link-to-image"></strong>
```

instead of

```
<strong><a rel="lightbox[gallery]" href="link-to-image"></strong>
```

This will validate as HTML5.